# How is FireFox running on a virtual machine that has no display?

Tags: ssh, process, firefox, top

I am using a Red Hat virtual machine, accessible only remotely. However when I use the `top` command, one of the displayed processes taking up the most memory is firefox, located at `/usr/lib64/firefox-3.0.18/firefox`.

How could such a process be launched without a display, and could it be actually used by some processes? Is there a way to check which processes are using it?

Comment: Are you the only person with access to that machine? If it's visible from the web, it have been compromised and someone might be running firefox via `ssh` with X forwarding. Check `who`, `netstat -n` and `lsof | grep firefox`.

Comment: Which virtualization software are you using? In VMWare, for example, virtual machines still have a display, even if nobody is connected via a virtual console.

Comment: VMWare indeed. Thank you @rozcietrzewiacz for these useful commands!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox needs an X display. This doesn't have to be a physical display on the machine where it's running: it can be a remote or virtual display.

If you want to know where it's displaying, look at the `DISPLAY` environment variable in the Firefox process. Note that you'll need to be root (or more precisely to have the permissions of the user running the firefox process).

```
</proc/$pid/environ grep -z '^DISPLAY='
```

If the value is of the form `:NUMBER` (beginning with a colon), the X server is local. There will be a socket called `/tmp/.X11-unix/XNUMBER`, e.g. `/tmp/.X11-unix/X42` for `DISPLAY=:42`. If the display is of the form `:NUMBER1.NUMBER2`, ignore the `.NUMBER2` part. Then run `lsof /tmp/.X11-unix/X42`; one of the processes that has that socket open is the X server. It's likely to be a virtual framebuffer X server like [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), or it could be a server for a remote display framework such as [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) or [NX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology).

If the value is of the form `host:NUMBER`, then the X display is remote. The X server is a process listening on port 6000+NUMBER. Run `netstat -plnt | awk '$4 ~ ":" (6000 + NUMBER) "$"' {print $7}` to show the PID of the process that's listening on that port. It's likely to be an ssh connection.

Comment: Why do you have `netstat` running with the `-l` and `-a` options? They do contradictory things.

Comment: @KevinM For no reason, here I'm looking for a listening socket so it should be `-l`. Thanks.

Comment: Should also be noted that ssh X11 forwarding will often end up with DISPLAY being something like `localhost:10`

Answer (score 0):

1. Since X11 is a Window system that allows the application server to be used to differ from the X server used, it is not neccessary to have a locally installed display.
2. Best thing would be to check which is the parent of the running firefox, i.e check the Parent's PID in the `ps` output (you may have to look at its parent also...). BTW: If you have a command like `ptree` installed, this helps a lot.
3. Annother indication would be the user-ID the process is using.